# Elasticsearch: Force merge reduced performance

Tags: elasticsearch

I forced merged my index to reduce segment size from 82 to 5, with the hope of increasing the search performance.

Dashboard load time for the same index was as follows,

82 segments - 10 seconds

5 segments - 250 seconds

As per the documents referred performance should be increased, any idea for this behavior?

My Data information

1 index only

5 shards

50 million docs

Index size (primary)

- 2 GB - after force merge
- 3.5GB - before force merge

Replicas - 1

My cluster information,

Es, kibana - 6.3.0 version

3 node cluster

15gb 4 core

7gb heap

400Gb disk per node

Comment: did you measure those numbers during the merge or just after? what kind of queries you're using usually?

Comment: it was just after merging

Comment: Could you warm up caches and do measurements after?

Answer (score 0):

This thread is already responded on the forum of elasticsearch
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/force-merge-reduced-performance/163838

> You should test your queries in the dev console and just look at the
> took field. Here you also have some browser rendering...
>
> Some comments:
>
> one shard is probably enough for your dataset test the search request
> multiple times as the OS cache is not used the very first time